# Resize sda1 while preserving sda2

Tags: linux

i've got a debian machine with the following layout:

```
*Disk /dev/sda: 110 GiB, 118111600640 bytes, 230686720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3f34cd54
Device     Boot    Start       End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048  96466943 96464896  46G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       96466944 104853503  8386560   4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris*
```

Now I resized sda to 110GB to get more space at sda1.
fdisk give's me these information:

```
*Disk /dev/sda: 110 GiB, 118111600640 bytes, 230686720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3f34cd54
Device     Boot    Start       End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048  96466943 96464896  46G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       96466944 104853503  8386560   4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris*
```

and

```
*Command (m for help): F
Unpartitioned space /dev/sda: 60 GiB, 64426606592 bytes, 125833216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes*
```

When I now just delete and recreate sda1 whit "other" numbers I suppose that my sda2 is gone, is it?

How do I resize sda1 so that the unallocated 60GB are added to sda1 without loosing sda2. Can I just "move" sda2 to the end of the sectors and then extend sda1? What is the best way to get this done?

Comment: sda2 is just swap? for swap it's usually delete and re-create as you will, no special steps necessary to preserve anything

Comment: Both `fdisk` listings look very the same to me...

Answer (score 2):

Before editing the partition table, run  `swapoff /dev/sda2` to tell the system to stop using the swap partition. After that, you can just remove it and re-create it however you want (first create the partition, then run `mkswap` on it).

If the swap happens to be specified in `/etc/fstab` by UUID, deleting and re-creating the swap partition will create a new UUID. Use `blkid` or `swaplabel` commands to find out the new UUID and edit `/etc/fstab` to match it in that case.

Once you're done, finally run `swapon -a` to re-activate the swap partition according to the configuration in `/etc/fstab` (thus verifying the correctness of it at the same time).

To resize (extend) the filesystem on `sda1` after the partition has been successfully modified, use `fsadm resize /dev/sda1`, or use a filesystem-specific tool: `resize2fs` for ext2/ext3/ext4 filetypes, `xfs_growfs` for XFS, and so on.

Debian-specific: If this is a laptop or you're otherwise using suspend/hibernate features, also check `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`; if it exists and refers to the swap partition, fix it too if necessary. If you need to modify this file, run `update-initramfs -u` afterwards.

Comment: After resizing the partition it might be good to resize the filesystem as well ;-)

Comment: @Lambert good point, I fixated on sda2 as it seemed to be the original poster's main issue.